# SQL consult joining two tables, group and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables that i need to consult with one query, i have the `Participante` table that will store some data from the user and the `ParticipanteResultado` that will store the answers of that user.

Table `Participante`

```
participanteID,
tipo,
**other fields**
```

The field `tipo` from `Participante` is used by the EF so i could receive the data from the query

Table `ParticipanteResultado`

```
participanteResultadoID,
participanteID,
tipo,
quantidadeValidas
```

My `ParticipanteResultado` table can have around 10 results per user, which will be different on the `tipo` that can be (A, B, C, D...).

```
participanteResultadoID participanteID tipo quantidadeValidas
4                       88              S   5
5                       88              E   5
```

What i need is to display the user data and his best result. By best result i mean the result that have the highest value on `quantidadeValidas` field. I already managed to do that with the following query:

```
SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone,
(SELECT TOP(1) tipo FROM ParticipanteResultado pr
WHERE p.participanteID = pr.participanteID
ORDER BY quantidadeValidas DESC) AS tipo FROM Participante p
```

My problem is, in the example i gave of the `ParticipanteResultado` data i have the user `88` with a tie and i need to bring those two values, they can be in the same column like (S, E).

UPDATE

This is my result from the query:

```
participanteID  nome             email                       unidadeCE   telefone        tipo
69              teste teste      teste@teste.com.br          42657       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
70              ana paula teste  teste@pearson.com           42182       (19) 1111-11111 NULL
71              testes           testes@testes.com           36513       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
83              teste teste      teste@teste.com.br          36513       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
84              ana teste        teste@hotmail.com           36921       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
85              Ana Paula        teste@pearson.com           36503       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
86              Claudio          teste@raioxfilmes.com.br    36830       (11) 1111-11111 NULL
87              Joana D'Arc      teste@ig.com.br             42855       (11) 1111-11111 NULL
88              teste teste      teste@teste.com.br          41925       (11) 11111-1111 E
89              Claudia Caroline teste@gmail.com             36355       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
90              Aline Souza      teste@gmail.com             36888       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
91              Samuel Oliveira  teste@ig.com.br             39401       (11) 11111-1111 NULL
```

P.S. I'm using this query on c# Entity Framework with my db context

Comment: You could get all the data back and put it into an array. Iterate through that array and display the data one line at a time. I realize there are less mechanical ways of doing it but this is an easy way for beginners to learn queries and how to handle their results.

Comment: I stick by my original answer...

Comment: The thing is i need to bring that data in one query so i can populate my objects, to do so i need to improve my query

Comment: I hope you are not publishing real confidential info in this post, aren't you??

Comment: No, they are test data

Comment: Read about the STUFF function in sql. It's going to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the data in terms of sets.

You need a set of data which is of all participants and all of their scores
and a set of the max quantidadeValidas by participant

So first get a list of the max quantidadeValidas for each participant

```
SELECT MAX(PR.quantidadeValidas), PR.participanteID
FROM ParticipanteResultado PR
GROUP BY participanteID
```

Now get the participants and scores.

```
SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone,
FROM Participante p
INNER JOIN ParticipanteResultado PR
 on p.participanteID = pr.participanteID
```

So now that we have both sets of data we need to limit all the scores to only the max, so join both sets together.  Using common table expressions for each of the above queries, and then the join should give you the desired results keeping the ties.

```
with maxScores as (
    SELECT MAX(PR.quantidadeValidas) maxScore, PR.participanteID
    FROM ParticipanteResultado PR
    GROUP BY participanteID
    ), 
    CompleteSet as (
    SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, PR.tipo PR.quantidadeValidas
    FROM Participante p
    INNER JOIN ParticipanteResultado PR
      on p.participanteID = pr.participanteID)
   SELECT CS.participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, tipo
   FROM maxScores MS
   INNER JOIN CompleteSet CS
    on MS.MaxScore = CS.QuantidadeValidas
   and CS.ParticipanteID = MS.ParticipanteID
```

Or without a CTE (Common Table Expression) as... (but much harder to read In my opinion)

```
   SELECT CS.participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, tipo 
   FROM (
      SELECT MAX(PR.quantidadeValidas) maxScore, PR.participanteID
      FROM ParticipanteResultado PR
      GROUP BY participanteID) MS
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, PR.tipo PR.quantidadeValidas
        FROM Participante p
        INNER JOIN ParticipanteResultado PR
          on p.participanteID = pr.participanteID) CS
    on MS.MaxScore = CS.QuantidadeValidas
   and CS.ParticipanteID = MS.ParticipanteID
```

Now if you want only one row when there is a tie, you'd have to use Stuff, or forXMLpath to combine multiple rows into one... but as you're expected result doesn't show how you envision ties to work, I went with the multiple row concept. instead of combining values into Tipo column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the top result for each participant, I'd go with the rank function:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   participanteID ,
                        nome ,
                        email ,
                        unidadeCE ,
                        telefone ,
                        tipo ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY participanteID ORDER BY tipo DESC ) AS rnk
               FROM     ParticipanteResultado
             )
    SELECT DISTINCT
            participanteID ,
            nome ,
            email ,
            unidadeCE ,
            telefone ,
            SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ',' + t1.tipo AS [text()]
                        FROM    cte t1
                        WHERE   t1.participanteID = t2.participanteID
                                AND t1.rnk = 1
                        ORDER BY t1.participanteID
                      FOR
                        XML PATH('')
                      ), 2, 1000) [tipos]
    FROM    ParticipanteResultado t2
    WHERE   t2.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into CTE or for xml path. The values need to be combined into one field but it will take another sub-query to do that.

```
SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, 
tipos=
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT  ', ' + CAST(tipo AS NVARCHAR(10))
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM ParticipanteResultado WHERE participanteID=X2.UserID
        )AS X2                      
        ORDER BY tipo FOR XML PATH( '' )
    ), 3, 1000 )
FROM Participante p
```